# How can a module detect when the "access denied" page is output?

Tags: 7

How is it possible for a module to detect when Drupal is outputting the "access denied" page?
I know how to do it with Drupal 6; I need to know how to do it with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do this in Boost 7.x. It's not pretty, but it does get the job done.

- [hook_page_delivery_callback_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_delivery_callback_alter/7)
- [boost_page_delivery_callback_alter()](http://drupalcode.org/project/boost.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/boost.module#l268)
- [boost_deliver_html_page()](http://drupalcode.org/project/boost.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/boost.module#l1195)

```
function boost_page_delivery_callback_alter(&$callback, $set = FALSE) {
  if ($callback == 'drupal_deliver_html_page') {
    $callback = 'boost_deliver_html_page';
  }
}

function boost_deliver_html_page($page_callback_result) {
  global $_boost;

  // Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string or array.
  if (is_int($page_callback_result)) {
    // @todo: Break these up into separate functions?
    switch ($page_callback_result) {

      // …

      case MENU_ACCESS_DENIED:
        // 403 page.
        $_boost['menu_item']['status'] = 403;
        break;

      // …

    }
    // …
  }
  // …   
}
```

Comment: This one is a big hack but it works : what you are doing is called hijacking. You plug your own code at an earlier point, and then reproduce the core code with a minimal modification.

Answer (score 13):

You can set which pages are displayed when 403 & 404 errors occurs (admin/settings/error-reporting).

I guess you can add a new page in your `hook_menu()`, then set this page as the 403 error callback. When your custom menu callback is hit, you know you're outputting the "access denied" page!

Comment: This is not a good solution for me as this is changing the output, not only detecting the 403.

Answer (score 10):

In Drupal 7, the function that returns the already set HTTP headers is [drupal_get_http_header()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_http_header/7), which requires the HTTP header name as parameter.
Looking at [authorize_access_denied_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/authorize.php/function/authorize_access_denied_page/7), and [drupal_fast_404()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_fast_404/7) code makes clear which values to pass to that function.

```
  // authorize_access_denied_page()
  drupal_add_http_header('Status', '403 Forbidden');
  watchdog('access denied', 'authorize.php', NULL, WATCHDOG_WARNING);
  drupal_set_title('Access denied');
  return t('You are not allowed to access this page.');
```

```
// drupal_fast_404()
if ($fast_paths && preg_match($fast_paths, $_GET['q'])) {
  drupal_add_http_header('Status', '404 Not Found');
  $fast_404_html = variable_get('404_fast_html', '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL "@path" was not found on this server.</p></body></html>');
  // Replace @path in the variable with the page path.
  print strtr($fast_404_html, array('@path' => check_plain(request_uri())));
  exit;
}
```

When the "Status" header starts with *403*, then Drupal output an access denied page.

Make sure the call to `drupal_get_http_header('Status')` happens late. Calling during `hook_init()` is too soon, but calling it during `hook_page_alter()` (or any theme preprocess hook) will have the updated header information.

Comment: This one is really the good answer. Just one point to note however : it seems to work only if the page is not cached. If the page has already been accessed before, the `drupal_get_http_header('Status')` returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

Your module could intercept the value of "`Default 403 (access denied) page`" which is modified by the page "`Administer > Site configuration > Error reporting`":

1. In `hook_enable`, using `variable_get`/`variable_set`, **copy the existing value** to a secondary variable and **replace the variable by your own** path (which you registered using `hook_menu`).
2. **alter the "Error reporting" form** using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` to read from/write to the secondary variable
3. If you want to be completely invisible to the user, your page callback to could call `drupal_goto( the_value_of_the_secondary_variable )`.
4. In `hook_disable`, **restore the value** from the secondary variable.

---

And that's it, your module gets notified **in a clean way** (and invisible to the user) when "Access denied" is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Surely you could use PHP's `get_headers()` function?

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

The first element in the array returned will be the response code. If it contains '403' then Drupal returned an "access denied" page.

I'm not sure where the best place to call it would be. Probably `hook_exit()`, depending on your needs:

> http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_exit/6

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way to detect Access Denied (403) and Page Not Found (404) in Drupal 7.

```
// get the menu router item for the current page
$router_item = menu_get_item();

// if there is no router item, this page is not found
$is_page_not_found_404 = empty($router_item);

// if 'access' is empty for the router item, access is denied
$is_access_denied_403 = empty($router_item['access']);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module for this.

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained permissions.