# Number of calls of hook_node_access

Tags: 7, users

I use hook_node_access() to redirect users, if they don't have the right attributes to see a specific node.

While programming I used dpm() to check some variables and was wondering, that dpm() is called 9 times although I just opened a single node.

Well, my question is:
Is it normal, that hook_node_access is called several times for one node, so I should use drupal_static() to avoid duplicate calculations or do I have some disadvantageous loops in my code that I should detect and remove (in hook_node_access are no loops, I mean somewhere else)?

I would welcome every advise!

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Are you sure it's for the same node?

Comment: Hm. I checked the $node variable and you are right. It is not always the same node. It is also called for all the other node types I have defined and in this case the $node variable just contains the type as string instead of an object.
And altough I just view a single node (e.g. node/123) the $op variable also contains 'update' and 'create' for these types and also for the viewed node. The next thing is, that it seems that this hook is called again after the request, because I also get one message ($op == 'view') after leaving the node to the admin config page for example. How can this be?

Comment: Ok the reason why the hook is called after the page request itself, are the private images in the node. Is there a way to avoid to call hook_node_access for images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [drupal_static](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) only operates within the scope of a single page request.

> All functions requiring a static variable to persist or cache data
>   within a single page request are encouraged to use this function
>   unless it is absolutely certain that the static variable will not need
>   to be reset during the page request.

I tend to think that using drupal_static might not help you, unless you can see that Drupal is calling your hook multiple times for the same node within a single page request.

I would say it **is** common to see a lot of calls to your hook.  For example, Drupal needs to check access for any link you put on a menu - if access is not allowed, then the menu item is hidden.

Another possible approach is to use [hook_node_access_records](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records/7)().  Drupal caches the result of this call in the node_access table, so your function will only get called when the node is saved.  See the [node access example](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/node_access_example!node_access_example.module/group/node_access_example/7).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Yes you are right. I realised, that the private images in the node causes this hook called multiple times. I really would like to use hook_node_access_records. But I need a redirect if permission is denied and I also need to calculate the current distance of the user to the location attached to a node. And I don't see a way to accomplish both features with hook_node_access_records()

Comment: Well you should be able to redirect on access denied, for example see [this answer] (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/327/how-can-a-module-detect-when-drupal-is-outputting-the-access-denied-page).  For the other part, I think you are telling me that your access decision involves the distance between the user location and the node location.  I have some ideas, but it's hard for me to answer that in a comment - perhaps you could ask a new question (link it in a comment from here) and accept my answer to this one?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the advise for the redirect. I'm really interested in your ideas with the access records. I have a new question [link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154149/deny-location-based-access-to-nodes). I accept your answer here, if we find a solution in the other question ;-)

Comment: Hehe OK, done.  I'm new to this site and need some rep before I can perform basic actions such as leaving comments, so please help me out if I've helped you.

Comment: Unfortunately your provided options don't fit my requirements. But I gave you +1 for your suggestions here. Thanks, keep it up and you will get your rep!

Comment: Cheers Daniel.  I realise you haven't solved your **overall problem**.  But this specific question seems answered (multiple calls is normal, probably drupal_static won't help).  If you agree, why not to mark it as answered so other people understand the status.  Meanwhile your other questions will help you reach your overall solution.

Answer (score 1):

Next time I should look into the docs first...

According to [node_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/7), it doesn't consider the returned value NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE, which I return, if the user doesn't violate my permissions, so that other modules still can deny access, if their permissions might be violated.

So the answer of my question is: I should use drupal_static() to avoid duplicate calculations.